How to format int cells with formatting while ignoring blank cells in pandas
I am writing a program in Pandas to compare the same two data sets at different time intervals. Once those comparisons are complete, the dataframes will be exported to excel. I'm having an issue trying to format the numbers of employee IDs. An employee number is 8 digits total, with zeros leading. An example would be 00045642. Normally when these numbers are produced excel drops the leading zeros until further formatted.
The map function updates the format with the 8 total digits but it creates two issues: When it exports to excel, excel has the digits as custom rather than an integer and it provides an error on the excel sheet. I have tried putting the .astype function before and after .map function but it still creates the error.
The second issue is not all cells in the columns I want to turn into integers have a value, causing the blanks to become 000000nan - which is not what I want.
I would like to skip any blank cells in the columns designated and the columns that do have numbers to format with 8 total digits and I would like the excel export to obviously not produce an error.
Note - the lambda function note that is on here is something I found that I believe is close to what I want but I can't get it work properly.
import pandas as pd   
import numpy as np

#new_WFRL  
new_WFRL = pd.read_excel("H:/DIR/Human Resources/HR Audits/Raw Files/WFRL 6.10.24.xlsx", usecols=["Empl ID", "Name",'Reports To', 'Reports To Position Number', 'Reports To Empl ID']).sort_values("Name")  
new_WFRL = new_WFRL.add_prefix("New ")  

#old_WFRL  
old_WFRL = pd.read_excel("H:/DIR/Human Resources/HR Audits/Raw Files/WFRL 4.18.24.xlsx", usecols=["Empl ID", "Name",'Reports To', 'Reports To Position Number', 'Reports To Empl ID']).sort_values("Name")  
old_WFRL = old_WFRL.add_prefix("Old ")  

merged_WFRL = pd.merge(old_WFRL, new_WFRL, how = "outer", left_on = "Old Empl ID", right_on = "New Empl ID")  
#merged_WFRL  

#this is the function that will show a change  
def compare_WFRL(df):  
    if df["Old Reports To"] == df["New Reports To"]:  
        return 1  
    else:  
        return 0  

#applies the above function  
merged_WFRL["changes"] = merged_WFRL.apply(compare_WFRL, axis =1)  
merged_WFRL  


#filters by lines that have changed   



#pd.options.display.float_format = lambda x : '{:,.2f}'.format(x) if (np.isnan(x) | np.isinf(x)) else '{:,.0f}'.format(x) if int(x) == x else '{:,.2f}'.format(x)

merged_WFRL[['Old Empl ID','Old Reports To Empl ID','New Empl ID', 'New Reports To Empl ID']] = merged_WFRL[['Old Empl ID','Old Reports To Empl ID','New Empl ID', 'New Reports To Empl ID']].astype(int, errors = 'ignore')

'''
merged_WFRL[['Old Empl ID','Old Reports To Empl ID','New Empl ID', 
            'New Reports To Empl ID']] = merged_WFRL[['Old Empl ID','Old Reports To Empl ID',
                                                       'New Empl ID', 'New Reports To Empl ID']].map('{:08.0f}'.format)
'''


# Define a function to format integers with leading zeros
def format_employee_id(x):
    if pd.notnull(x):
        return f"{int(x):08d}"  # Formats as integer with leading zeros
    else:
        return ""  # Return empty string for NaN or None values

# Apply the formatting function using applymap
merged_WFRL[['Old Empl ID','Old Reports To Empl ID','New Empl ID','New Reports To Empl ID']] = merged_WFRL[['Old Empl ID','Old Reports To Empl ID',
                                                                                                            'New Empl ID','New Reports To Empl ID']].map(format_employee_id)

#merged_WFRL[['Old Empl ID','Old Reports To Empl ID','New Empl ID', 'New Reports To Empl ID']] = merged_WFRL[['Old Empl ID','Old Reports To Empl ID','New Empl ID', 'New Reports To Empl ID']].astype(int, errors = 'ignore')

merged_changes = merged_WFRL[merged_WFRL["changes"] == 0] 
merged_changes.pop('changes')                 



#merged_WFRL.info()




# Export DataFrame to Excel
export_file = "H:/DIR/Human Resources/HR Audits/Reports To Changes/6.10.24 Coach Changesv14.xlsx"
 
#index= False means that the index column is dropped
# export file will be later referenced in the wb = load_workbook(export_file)
merged_changes.to_excel(export_file, index=False, engine='openpyxl') 

######################################################################################################
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions import ColumnDimension, DimensionHolder
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter #takes an integer betwween 1-26 A=1, B=2 etc. 
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle, Border, Side, Font, Color, colors, Alignment, PatternFill
from openpyxl.descriptors import String, Sequence, Integer
from openpyxl.descriptors.serialisable import Serialisable


# Load the workbook and select the active worksheet
wb = load_workbook(export_file)
ws = wb.active
ws.title= 'Reports To Changes' #names the sheet tab

# Define cell styles
yellow_fill = PatternFill(start_color="FFFF00", end_color="FFFF00", fill_type="solid")


# Apply conditional formatting
'''
#dynamic counting - starts at row 2 and goes the length of the rows. 
Basically the +2 allows to the program to auto count the rows
'''
for row in range(2, len(merged_changes) + 2):    
    old_reports_to_cell = ws.cell(row=row, column=5)  # Old coach
    new_reports_to_cell = ws.cell(row=row, column=10)  # New coach
    
    
    # Check for New Grade not equal to Old Grade
    if new_reports_to_cell.value != old_reports_to_cell.value:
        new_reports_to_cell.fill = yellow_fill
    
   
#centers the rows and columns. 
for row in range(2, len(merged_changes) + 2):
    for col in range(1,15):
        ws.cell(row,col).alignment = Alignment(horizontal = 'center')
        ws.cell(row,col).border = Border(left = Side(border_style='thin', color = 'FF000000'),
                                         right = Side(border_style = 'thin', color = 'FF000000'),
                                         top = Side(border_style = 'thin', color = 'FF000000'),
                                         bottom = Side(border_style = 'thin', color = 'FF000000'))

# Applys formating to column width
dims = {}
for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value:
            dims[cell.column_letter] = max((dims.get(cell.column_letter, 0), len(str(cell.value))))
           
for col, value in dims.items():
    ws.column_dimensions[col].width = value *1.2   #*1.2 added additional width to the column. The formatting didn't give it enough space, this expanded it further. 




# Save the workbook
wb.save(export_file)


Your question is missing a [mre] of the data

@mozway sorry the formatting didn't come out correctly - I see you fixed that. Do you still need more? This program requires uploading of an excel sheet that I can't provide. I can include the remainder program if that would make troubleshooting easier.

It's fine not to provide the original data, but then craft a dummy example to demonstrate your point with a reproducible example.

@mozway I have updated the entire program. Hopefully this is more helpful in determining an solution.

No it's not, what would have been useful is a MRE, see here for help on how to craft MREs for pandas
